Topology on the space of compactly supported functions
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological space, and let $C_c(X)$ be the space of compactly supported $\mathbf{R}$-valued continuous functions. It is a well-known fact that this space is not complete if we topologize $C_c(X)$ using the compact-open topology.
In order to fix this issue, usually one introduces a different topology on $C_c(X)$. Namely, for each compact subspace $K\subset X$, one considers the space $C_K(X)$ of continuous functions $f\colon X \to \mathbf{R}$ such that $\overline{\operatorname{supp}(f)}\subset K$. Then one easily sees that, as a vector space, $C_c(X) = \operatorname{colim}_{K\subset R} C_K(X)$. Now we topologize each $C_K(X)$ using the usual sup-norm, and we define the topology on $C_c(X)$ to be the topology of the colimit in the category of locally convex topological vector spaces.
If $X$ is a countable union of compact subspaces, then one can check that a sequence $(f_n) \in C_c(X)$ is Cauchy if and only if there is a compact $K$ such that $f_n\in C_K(X)$ for all but finitely many $f_n$ and these $f_n$ form a Cauchy sequence in $C_K(X)$. In particular, this implies that the space $C_c(X)$ is indeed complete in this topology.
But I fail to see whether the same description of convergent sequences holds for any locally compact Hausdorff $X$. In particular,
Question: is it true that $C_c(X)$ is always complete in the described topology?
It is tempting to try the following approach below, but I can't make it work.
Start with a sequence $(f_n) \in C_c(X)$, then there is a countable sequence of compacts $K_1\subset K_2\subset K_3\subset \dotsb $ such that $\overline{\operatorname{supp}(f_i)} \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbf{N}} K_n$ for each $i$. So this sequence already lies in $\operatorname{colim} C_{K_n}(X)$.
Now assume that the sequence $(f_n) \in C_c(X)$ is Cauchy. Then if we knew that this sequence is already Cauchy in $\operatorname{colim} C_{K_n}(X)$, we would be done because we would conclude that it essentially comes from a Cauchy sequence in some $C_{K_n}(X)$ (because this colimit is sequential). Therefore, one reduces the question to showing that the sequence $(f_n)$ is already Cauchy in $\operatorname{colim} C_{K_n}(X)$. But I can't see why this should be true.
Maybe a slightly more general question:
Question: Is it true that an $\aleph_0$-filtered colimit of complete locally convex topological vector spaces is complete?

Are you trying to show completeness, or only sequential completeness?

@LSpice Ah, thanks, I didn't appreciate the difference when I was writing the post! I would be curious to know the answers to both questions. But I was mostly interested in sequential completeness when I was writing the post.

The more general question is well-known: There are incomplete countable colimits of Banach spaces.

Your space is sequentially complete for any locally compact space, complete for paracompact such.

@terceira Do you have a reference for these claims?

The space $C_c(X)$ with the locally convex colimit topology is complete whenever $X$ is paracompact (this confirms the second claim in the comment of @terceira):
This is a theorem of Bierstedt proved in 11.8.17 of the book Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces of Bonet and Pérez Carreras.
On the other hand, 11.8.18 reports an example of Douady (Parties compactes d'un espace de fonctions continues à support compact, C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris 257, 2788-2791, 1963) that for $X=\beta\mathbb N \setminus \{a\}$ with $a$ in the remainder of the Stone-Cech compactification, the space $C_c(X)$ is not even sequentially complete (this is in contrast to the first claim in the comment mentioned above).

Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! For 1), the key observation that I didn't realize before is that every locally compact paracompact space is a disjoint union of sigma-compact spaces. Then it follows from the observation that both strict colimits and arbitrary direct sums preserve completeness.
Is it easy to see the idea why $C_c(\beta{\mathbf{N}} \smallsetminus {a})$ is not sequentially complete? [It seems difficult to find Douady's paper online]

Bonet and Pérez Carreras call this a delicate result. Perhaps you have luck with this link https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4009k/f24.item
